# Spring Batch CSV File to MongoDB: Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured

Tags: mongodb, csv, spring-batch, batch-processing

I'm running a batch processing sample that reads data from CSVFile and Write it to MongoDB.
Spring Data MongoDB, Spring Batch starters are added along with the below details.

**application.properties:**

```
#Spring batch configuration
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always

#Mongodb configuration
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=ntspbms715db
spring.data.mongodb.username=testuser
spring.data.mongodb.password=testuser
```

I'm hitting the below error, and it be fixed by adding `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})` in main class.

Now can anyone explain why am I hitting this issue and how the above fix resolved the error?

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Adding `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})` in main class is fixing the reported issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Spring Batch with Spring Boot, you need to define a datasource bean in your application context. This is mentioned in the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.batch.storing-job-repository). This is also true starting from Spring Batch v5 even without Spring Boot.

Moreover, the following property `spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always` instructs Spring Boot to initialize a JDBC datasource with Batch tables, which cannot be found.